# Unexpected branch name

Tags: tortoisegit

How have I managed to do this with TortoiseGit?

When I look at my log it is showing an try for "TruckleSoft". What did I do to get that result?

[image: Log]

It seems that somehow I managed to push my changes to a branch called TruckleSoft instead of my usual **master**. Does this matter now? Is it safe to just delete this branch on the remote site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe to just delete this branch on the remote site?

Yes, it's safe to delete for the reason: **`origin/master` is ahead of `origin/TruckleSoft`**. So, you do not lose any commits after deleting it.

For now, `origin/TruckleSoft` is just a useless label.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you fetched all refs, and is now seeing a remote branch (possibly from a different user), who pushed branch, TruckleSoft.

It is not safe to delete this branch, unless the rest of your team is okay with losing TruckleSoft as a remote branch.

EDIT: Yue Lin Ho is correct in, that changes to the repository will not be lost if you delete the branch, but it is entirely different whether your team expects the remote branch to exist or not.